# intellisense in vb6 doens't work with Interop and UnmanagedType.Struct

Tags: c#, vb6, interop, intellisense, variant

I have a c# interop class with this property:

```
decimal ImportoDocumento { [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] get; [param: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] set; }
```

In vb6 it should be a Variant/Decimal. 
If i try to use it, it works. I can assign a value and i can get its value.
The problem is that the vb6 intellisense doesn't work.
I can see the other properties of the class but not ImportoDocumento.
The intellisense is important because this class is used from other people.

How can i do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the method is missing from IntelliSense is because the type library exporter gives you two warnings:

> Type library exporter warning processing 'ClassLibrary1.Class1.get_ImportoDocumento(#0), ClassLibrary1'.
>   Warning: The method or field has an invalid ELEMENT_TYPE/NATIVE_TYPE combination.
>
> Type library exporter warning processing 'ClassLibrary1.Class1.set_ImportoDocumento(value), ClassLibrary1'.
>   Warning: The method or field has an invalid ELEMENT_TYPE/NATIVE_TYPE combination.

Unable to generate a proper TLB information for this property, the exporter omits it entirely, as if you used `[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDispatch)]`. Without this information, the property is only available for late binding, which is why it still works.

You need to [declare the property as `Object`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2x07fbw8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to have it marshaled as Variant.